# How can I destroy fotorama

Tags: fotorama

I use fotorama with html frames. The html may change during site work. Unfortunately(?), frames disappear from page after first initialization of fotorama. So, I want to destroy fotorama, change html in frames and start it again. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer in source code.

> $(selector).data('fotorama').destroy()

Answer (score 3):

This is actually available from the [documentation](http://fotorama.io/customize/api/)

```
// 1. Initialize fotorama manually.
var $fotoramaDiv = $('#fotorama').fotorama();

// 2. Get the API object.
var fotorama = $fotoramaDiv.data('fotorama');
```

then you'll be able to

```
fotorama.destroy();
```

Note that if the fotorama div is **hidden**, you'll not be able to get the API object and thus not be able to destroy fotorama.

Comment: Yes, now docs are much better and the library too. A year ago this information really was able only in sources.